# With parallax/transform/perspective css, how to prevent background elements from showing up on top?

Tags: css

I'm having issues trying to get parallax scrolling to work when using the `perspective` and `transform` css declarations. The transformations work fine, but the elements in the background show above the rest of the elements on the page. It is as though the background elements have a higher `z-index` than the foreground elements, even thought I'm not using `z-index` at all! I was under the impression that stacking contexts lost most of their meaning once 3d transformations come in to play.

Here's a minimal example of the problem:

```css
html {
  overflow: hidden;
}

body {
  overflow: auto;
  perspective: 3000px;
  height: 500px;
}

.background {
  background-color: lightblue;
  transform: translateZ(-5000px)
}

.foreground {
  position: absolute;
}
```

```html
<body class="perspective-container">
  <div class="foreground">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Cras et congue nulla, id sodales quam. Nulla semper non sapien ac faucibus. Cras eu diam eu felis rutrum fermentum id eu nunc. Aenean ipsum odio, pulvinar non pulvinar eu, gravida vitae leo. Pellentesque habitant morbi tristique senectus et netus et malesuada fames ac turpis egestas. Phasellus ex nisl, cursus non risus commodo, maximus ornare velit. Ut ac laoreet dolor, vitae bibendum risus. Nam venenatis eleifend enim eget aliquet. Maecenas consequat augue eu metus imperdiet venenatis. Ut venenatis ante bibendum arcu auctor interdum. Donec finibus metus sed luctus suscipit. Praesent porttitor feugiat quam blandit aliquam. Ut rhoncus dolor id diam bibendum molestie. Cras dolor sem, bibendum eget eleifend id, ornare non turpis. Nunc finibus cursus nisi, nec pulvinar tortor imperdiet in. Phasellus mi dui, malesuada sit amet velit at, rutrum ullamcorper massa. Nam viverra risus ornare rutrum rhoncus. Proin imperdiet pulvinar ex, ut lobortis ipsum rhoncus at.Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Cras et congue nulla, id sodales quam. Nulla semper non sapien ac faucibus. Cras eu diam eu felis rutrum fermentum id eu nunc. Aenean ipsum odio, pulvinar non pulvinar eu, gravida vitae leo. Pellentesque habitant morbi tristique senectus et netus et malesuada fames ac turpis egestas. Phasellus ex nisl, cursus non risus commodo, maximus ornare velit. Ut ac laoreet dolor, vitae bibendum risus.Nam venenatis eleifend enim eget aliquet. Maecenas consequat augue eu metus imperdiet venenatis. Ut venenatis ante bibendum arcu auctor interdum. Donec finibus metus sed luctus suscipit. Praesent porttitor feugiat quam blandit aliquam. Ut rhoncus dolor id diam bibendum molestie. Cras dolor sem, bibendum eget eleifend id, ornare non turpis. Nunc finibus cursus nisi, nec pulvinar tortor imperdiet in. Phasellus mi dui, malesuada sit amet velit at, rutrum ullamcorper massa. Nam viverra risus ornare rutrum rhoncus. Proin imperdiet pulvinar ex, ut lobortis ipsum rhoncus at. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Cras et congue nulla, id sodales quam. Nulla semper non sapien ac faucibus. Cras eu diam eu felis rutrum fermentum id eu nunc. Aenean ipsum odio, pulvinar non pulvinar eu, gravida vitae leo. Pellentesque habitant morbi tristique senectus et netus et malesuada fames ac turpis egestas. Phasellus ex nisl, cursus non risus commodo, maximus ornare velit. Ut ac laoreet dolor, vitae bibendum risus. Nam venenatis eleifend enim eget aliquet. Maecenas consequat augue eu metus imperdiet venenatis. Ut venenatis ante bibendum arcu auctor interdum. Donec finibus metus sed luctus suscipit. Praesent porttitor feugiat quam blandit aliquam. Ut rhoncus dolor id diam bibendum molestie. Cras dolor sem, bibendum eget eleifend id, ornare non turpis. Nunc finibus cursus nisi, nec pulvinar tortor imperdiet in. Phasellus mi dui, malesuada sit amet velit at, rutrum ullamcorper massa. Nam viverra risus ornare rutrum rhoncus. Proin imperdiet pulvinar ex, ut lobortis ipsum rhoncus at.Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Cras et congue nulla, id sodales quam. Nulla semper non sapien ac faucibus. Cras eu diam eu felis rutrum fermentum id eu nunc. Aenean ipsum odio, pulvinar non pulvinar eu, gravida vitae leo. Pellentesque habitant morbi tristique senectus et netus et malesuada fames ac turpis egestas. Phasellus ex nisl, cursus non risus commodo, maximus ornare velit. Ut ac laoreet dolor, vitae bibendum risus.Nam venenatis eleifend enim eget aliquet. Maecenas consequat augue eu metus imperdiet venenatis. Ut venenatis ante bibendum arcu auctor interdum. Donec finibus metus sed luctus suscipit. Praesent porttitor feugiat quam blandit aliquam. Ut rhoncus dolor id diam bibendum molestie. Cras dolor sem, bibendum eget eleifend id, ornare non turpis. Nunc finibus cursus nisi, nec pulvinar tortor imperdiet in. Phasellus mi dui, malesuada sit amet velit at, rutrum ullamcorper massa. Nam viverra risus ornare rutrum rhoncus. Proin imperdiet pulvinar ex, ut lobortis ipsum rhoncus at.</div>
  <div class="background">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Cras et congue nulla, id sodales quam. Nulla semper non sapien ac faucibus. Cras eu diam eu felis rutrum fermentum id eu nunc. Aenean ipsum odio, pulvinar non pulvinar eu, gravida vitae leo. Pellentesque habitant morbi tristique senectus et netus et malesuada fames ac turpis egestas. Phasellus ex nisl, cursus non risus commodo, maximus ornare velit. Ut ac laoreet dolor, vitae bibendum risus.Nam venenatis eleifend enim eget aliquet. Maecenas consequat augue eu metus imperdiet venenatis. Ut venenatis ante bibendum arcu auctor interdum. Donec finibus metus sed luctus suscipit. Praesent porttitor feugiat quam blandit aliquam. Ut rhoncus dolor id diam bibendum molestie. Cras dolor sem, bibendum eget eleifend id, ornare non turpis. Nunc finibus cursus nisi, nec pulvinar tortor imperdiet in. Phasellus mi dui, malesuada sit amet velit at, rutrum ullamcorper massa. Nam viverra risus ornare rutrum rhoncus. Proin imperdiet pulvinar ex, ut lobortis ipsum rhoncus at.Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Cras et congue nulla, id sodales quam. Nulla semper non sapien ac faucibus. Cras eu diam eu felis rutrum fermentum id eu nunc. Aenean ipsum odio, pulvinar non pulvinar eu, gravida vitae leo. Pellentesque habitant morbi tristique senectus et netus et malesuada fames ac turpis egestas. Phasellus ex nisl, cursus non risus commodo, maximus ornare velit. Ut ac laoreet dolor, vitae bibendum risus.Nam venenatis eleifend enim eget aliquet. Maecenas consequat augue eu metus imperdiet venenatis. Ut venenatis ante bibendum arcu auctor interdum. Donec finibus metus sed luctus suscipit. Praesent porttitor feugiat quam blandit aliquam. Ut rhoncus dolor id diam bibendum molestie. Cras dolor sem, bibendum eget eleifend id, ornare non turpis. Nunc finibus cursus nisi, nec pulvinar tortor imperdiet in. Phasellus mi dui, malesuada sit amet velit at, rutrum ullamcorper massa. Nam viverra risus ornare rutrum rhoncus. Proin imperdiet pulvinar ex, ut lobortis ipsum rhoncus at.</div>
</body>
```

I've tried adding `transform-style: preserve-3d`, but that didn't help:

```
* {
    transform-style: preserve-3d;
}
```

How do I get the background to be in the background? Why doesn't `transform-style: preserve-3d` fix this problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

## How do I get the background to be in the background?

Wrap the children of the perspective container with an element that has `transform-style: preserve-3d`:

```css
html {
  overflow: hidden;
}

.wrapper {
  transform-style: preserve-3d;
}

body {
  overflow: auto;
  perspective: 3000px;
  height: 500px;
}

.background {
  background-color: lightblue;
  transform: translateZ(-5000px)
}

.foreground {
  position: absolute;
}
```

```html
<body class="perspective-container">
  <div class="wrapper">
    <div class="foreground">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Cras et congue nulla, id sodales quam. Nulla semper non sapien ac faucibus. Cras eu diam eu felis rutrum fermentum id eu nunc. Aenean ipsum odio, pulvinar non pulvinar eu, gravida vitae leo. Pellentesque habitant morbi tristique senectus et netus et malesuada fames ac turpis egestas. Phasellus ex nisl, cursus non risus commodo, maximus ornare velit. Ut ac laoreet dolor, vitae bibendum risus. Nam venenatis eleifend enim eget aliquet. Maecenas consequat augue eu metus imperdiet venenatis. Ut venenatis ante bibendum arcu auctor interdum. Donec finibus metus sed luctus suscipit. Praesent porttitor feugiat quam blandit aliquam. Ut rhoncus dolor id diam bibendum molestie. Cras dolor sem, bibendum eget eleifend id, ornare non turpis. Nunc finibus cursus nisi, nec pulvinar tortor imperdiet in. Phasellus mi dui, malesuada sit amet velit at, rutrum ullamcorper massa. Nam viverra risus ornare rutrum rhoncus. Proin imperdiet pulvinar ex, ut lobortis ipsum rhoncus at.Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Cras et congue nulla, id sodales quam. Nulla semper non sapien ac faucibus. Cras eu diam eu felis rutrum fermentum id eu nunc. Aenean ipsum odio, pulvinar non pulvinar eu, gravida vitae leo. Pellentesque habitant morbi tristique senectus et netus et malesuada fames ac turpis egestas. Phasellus ex nisl, cursus non risus commodo, maximus ornare velit. Ut ac laoreet dolor, vitae bibendum risus.Nam venenatis eleifend enim eget aliquet. Maecenas consequat augue eu metus imperdiet venenatis. Ut venenatis ante bibendum arcu auctor interdum. Donec finibus metus sed luctus suscipit. Praesent porttitor feugiat quam blandit aliquam. Ut rhoncus dolor id diam bibendum molestie. Cras dolor sem, bibendum eget eleifend id, ornare non turpis. Nunc finibus cursus nisi, nec pulvinar tortor imperdiet in. Phasellus mi dui, malesuada sit amet velit at, rutrum ullamcorper massa. Nam viverra risus ornare rutrum rhoncus. Proin imperdiet pulvinar ex, ut lobortis ipsum rhoncus at. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Cras et congue nulla, id sodales quam. Nulla semper non sapien ac faucibus. Cras eu diam eu felis rutrum fermentum id eu nunc. Aenean ipsum odio, pulvinar non pulvinar eu, gravida vitae leo. Pellentesque habitant morbi tristique senectus et netus et malesuada fames ac turpis egestas. Phasellus ex nisl, cursus non risus commodo, maximus ornare velit. Ut ac laoreet dolor, vitae bibendum risus. Nam venenatis eleifend enim eget aliquet. Maecenas consequat augue eu metus imperdiet venenatis. Ut venenatis ante bibendum arcu auctor interdum. Donec finibus metus sed luctus suscipit. Praesent porttitor feugiat quam blandit aliquam. Ut rhoncus dolor id diam bibendum molestie. Cras dolor sem, bibendum eget eleifend id, ornare non turpis. Nunc finibus cursus nisi, nec pulvinar tortor imperdiet in. Phasellus mi dui, malesuada sit amet velit at, rutrum ullamcorper massa. Nam viverra risus ornare rutrum rhoncus. Proin imperdiet pulvinar ex, ut lobortis ipsum rhoncus at.Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Cras et congue nulla, id sodales quam. Nulla semper non sapien ac faucibus. Cras eu diam eu felis rutrum fermentum id eu nunc. Aenean ipsum odio, pulvinar non pulvinar eu, gravida vitae leo. Pellentesque habitant morbi tristique senectus et netus et malesuada fames ac turpis egestas. Phasellus ex nisl, cursus non risus commodo, maximus ornare velit. Ut ac laoreet dolor, vitae bibendum risus.Nam venenatis eleifend enim eget aliquet. Maecenas consequat augue eu metus imperdiet venenatis. Ut venenatis ante bibendum arcu auctor interdum. Donec finibus metus sed luctus suscipit. Praesent porttitor feugiat quam blandit aliquam. Ut rhoncus dolor id diam bibendum molestie. Cras dolor sem, bibendum eget eleifend id, ornare non turpis. Nunc finibus cursus nisi, nec pulvinar tortor imperdiet in. Phasellus mi dui, malesuada sit amet velit at, rutrum ullamcorper massa. Nam viverra risus ornare rutrum rhoncus. Proin imperdiet pulvinar ex, ut lobortis ipsum rhoncus at.</div>
    <div class="background">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Cras et congue nulla, id sodales quam. Nulla semper non sapien ac faucibus. Cras eu diam eu felis rutrum fermentum id eu nunc. Aenean ipsum odio, pulvinar non pulvinar eu, gravida vitae leo. Pellentesque habitant morbi tristique senectus et netus et malesuada fames ac turpis egestas. Phasellus ex nisl, cursus non risus commodo, maximus ornare velit. Ut ac laoreet dolor, vitae bibendum risus.Nam venenatis eleifend enim eget aliquet. Maecenas consequat augue eu metus imperdiet venenatis. Ut venenatis ante bibendum arcu auctor interdum. Donec finibus metus sed luctus suscipit. Praesent porttitor feugiat quam blandit aliquam. Ut rhoncus dolor id diam bibendum molestie. Cras dolor sem, bibendum eget eleifend id, ornare non turpis. Nunc finibus cursus nisi, nec pulvinar tortor imperdiet in. Phasellus mi dui, malesuada sit amet velit at, rutrum ullamcorper massa. Nam viverra risus ornare rutrum rhoncus. Proin imperdiet pulvinar ex, ut lobortis ipsum rhoncus at.Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Cras et congue nulla, id sodales quam. Nulla semper non sapien ac faucibus. Cras eu diam eu felis rutrum fermentum id eu nunc. Aenean ipsum odio, pulvinar non pulvinar eu, gravida vitae leo. Pellentesque habitant morbi tristique senectus et netus et malesuada fames ac turpis egestas. Phasellus ex nisl, cursus non risus commodo, maximus ornare velit. Ut ac laoreet dolor, vitae bibendum risus.Nam venenatis eleifend enim eget aliquet. Maecenas consequat augue eu metus imperdiet venenatis. Ut venenatis ante bibendum arcu auctor interdum. Donec finibus metus sed luctus suscipit. Praesent porttitor feugiat quam blandit aliquam. Ut rhoncus dolor id diam bibendum molestie. Cras dolor sem, bibendum eget eleifend id, ornare non turpis. Nunc finibus cursus nisi, nec pulvinar tortor imperdiet in. Phasellus mi dui, malesuada sit amet velit at, rutrum ullamcorper massa. Nam viverra risus ornare rutrum rhoncus. Proin imperdiet pulvinar ex, ut lobortis ipsum rhoncus at.</div>
  </div>
</body>
```

For this simple example, you could also just reorder the elements on the page, such that all backgrounds come before all foregrounds.

## Why doesn't `transform-style: preserve-3d` fix this problem?

**It does, but** any elements who are *direct* children of the perspective container will overlap in the usual stacking context rules. **I'm not sure why**.